# CNAME and WHM - how to stop domain name being appended automatically

Tags: email, dns, cpanel, cname, whm

Really quick one - I am attempting to use mailgun for my email.

One of the requirements is to add a `CNAME = mailgun.org`

I am attempting to do this via WHM - and can successfully create the record under 'Edit DNS Zone' for the domain.

The problem is that it is auto-appending my domain name after the 'mailgun.org' entry

So when I save the record gets saved as mailgun.org.mydomainname.com

How can I stop the auto-append of my domain name to a CNAME??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem the answer is simple - just add a fullstop after mailgun.org (mailgun.org`.`)

Simplest things but when you don't know them they can be a real pain!

Comment: this only works for the "address" value. Even with a fullstop it still appends my domain onto the "host" value

Comment: wow, I have been stumbled upon 2 days. Finally..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding an extra blank after entering mailgun.org.

So type the following: mailgun.org.(add a space after the final period)